# Dynamically Center Elements inside a Row

Tags: html, css, jstl

I have two Images with Links inside a `row`. Sometimes only one Image will be needed so I have added `JSTL` tags to verify that. The problem is when I'm displaying just one Image. Then they're not centered. Only when both the Images are available it's centered. How to tackle this?

```
<div class="row">
    <c:if test="${content.facebookLink ne 'NO_FACEBOOK_LINK'}">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6">
            <a href="${content.facebookLink}" target="_blank">
                <img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/fb.png"/>">
            </a>
        </div>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${content.twitterLink ne 'NO_TWITTER_LINK'}">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <a href="${content.twitterLink}" target="_blank">
                <img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/twitter.png "/>">
            </a>
        </div>
    </c:if>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way is to convert `.col-sm-3.col-xs-6` to `inline-block` element and use `text-center` class to `.row`

```css
.col-sm-3.col-xs-6 {
  display: inline-block;
  float:none;
  width:auto;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class=container>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
      <a href="${content.facebookLink}" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
      <a href="${content.twitterLink}" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class=container>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
      <a href="${content.twitterLink}" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution. Omitted he columns from the dynamic elements.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <c:if test="${content.facebookLink ne 'NO_FACEBOOK_LINK'}">
            <a href="${content.facebookLink}" target="_blank" style="display: inline">
                <img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/fb.png"/>">
            </a>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${content.twitterLink ne 'NO_TWITTER_LINK'}">
            <a href="${content.twitterLinkk}" target="_blank" style="display: inline">
                <img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/twitter.png "/>">
            </a>
        </c:if>
    </div>
</div>
```

Works perfect.

Comment: I thought you cannot change grid layout or HTML as it's dynamic, otherwise using `inline` element with `text-align:center` to parent is better option.